# Is there any default method for ENUM?

Tags: java, enums

I have enum class which consists of bigint constants.

```
public enum Constants {
    CONST1(new BigInteger("12783786")),
    CONST2(new BigInteger("489578758"));

    BigInteger id;

    Constants(BigInteger id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    BigInteger getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Is there any default method which will be called when enum is passed to a method as an argument. Now for a method like process(BigInteger id) i have to write code like process(CONST1.getId()). I want it to look like process(CONST1). Thanks a lot for answers.

Comment: Change the method signature to `process(Constants constant)`.  (This usage illustrates why enums typically have singular names.)

Comment: If you're trying to make constant `BigInteger` values, `public static final BigInteger`s might be a better choice than `enum`s.

Comment: I cant do that. These methods are provided by third-party library. Also some me process methods are used by other people and they use bigints.  I decided to use static fields in a common class but with a private default constructor. Thanks for answers

Comment: The duplicate discusses the problem for `String`. It's the same for `BigInteger` and your `getId` method.

Comment: I would say this is a misuse of `Enum`. You should just declare the various constants you need as static `BigInteger`.